# Win Batch File - Remove First File Extension

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, rename, batch-rename

Using `rename` command in a batch file in Windows is there a clear way for remove the First File Extension from all files in a directory. For example

```
1.txt.png => 1.png 
2.txt.png => 2.png
```

Now I use two renaming methods that work. But in my opinion, these methods look "dirty".

**1 method**. I don't like the 1st method because I exec `rename` twice.

```
rename *.txt.png *.
rename *.txt *.png
```

**2 method**. I don't like the 2nd method because the number of characters "?" can theoretically be smaller than the basic name (without extension) of the file.

```
rename *.txt.png ??????????????????????????????.png
```

**? Clear method**

I would like to run a command like `rename *.txt.png *.png` but it doesn't work.

Comment: What about the command line code `for /F "eol=| delims=" %I in ('dir /B /A:-D-H-S "*.txt.png"') do for %J in ("%~nI") do ren "%~I" "%~nJ%~xI"` (double the `%`-signs in a batch file)?

Comment: I think that the `rename` command can do the operation I need on its own. It’s just not clear how to correctly indicate wildcards

Comment: Well, @tecdocukrnet, I don't think that a plain `rename` command can do that, except for your 2nd method with enough `?`s – refer to this: [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards? \[Super User\]](https://superuser.com/a/475875)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `cmd` command that will rename the file as described. When you are confident that the file(s) will be renamed correctly, remove `-WhatIf` from the `Rename-Item` command.

If you are using the older Windows PowerShell instead of PowerShell Core, change `pwsh` to `powershell`.

```
pwsh -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Get-Childitem -Filter '*.*.*' |" ^
        "ForEach-Object {" ^
            "if ($_.Name -match '(.*)\..*(\..*)') {" ^
                "Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName ($($Matches[1])+$($Matches[2])) -WhatIf" ^
            "}" ^
        "}"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

for %%A in ("*.txt.*") do call :SubRen "%%A"

pause
exit/b

:SubRen
set "Name=%~1"
if /I not "%Name%" == "%Name:.txt.=.%" ECHO ren "%Name%" "%Name:.txt.=.%"
if /I not "%Name%" == "%Name:.txt.=.%" ren "%Name%" "%Name:.txt.=.%"
exit/b
```